# How to create a 3 column text file given 3 string arrays JAVA

Tags: java, text-files

I am trying to create a formatted text file programatically using java. Basically, I have 3 String type arrays and each array is supposed to be one column.

EX:

```
String column1[];
String column2[];
String column3[];

void ArraysToTextFile(String FilePath)
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Encapsulate your data in a class and its objects.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-off way is to
1. Open a FileOutputStream to the file to write the data into.
2. Use `String.format()` to get the row where each column is of specified width.
3. FileOutStream.write(byte[]) method to print the string in #2.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int =0; i<stringMaxLength; i++){
   if(column1.length<stringMaxLength)
      System.out.print(column1[i]);
   else System.out.print(0);
   if(column2.length<stringMaxLength)
      System.out.print(column2[i]);
   else System.out.print(0);
   if(column3.length<stringMaxLength)
      System.out.print(column3[i]);
   else System.out.print(0);

   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Calculate your stringMaxLength with the Math.max methods